# OpenMP error: Invalid controlling predicate

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a for loop and I get the error:
Invalid controlling predicate

The loop I want to parallelize is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : sum)
    for (i = 1; i <= input; i++)
        x = m * ( double ) ( 2 * i - 1 );
        sum = sum + 1.5 / ( 1.0 + x * x );
```

I read how the for loop must be structured in OpenMP (Canonical Loop Form) and I think I am respecting it.

I tried to parallelize it by using sections and the compilation was fine, but I don't understand why the code above is not working.

How I structured sections that worked:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(x,sum) private(i)
{
    #pragma omp sections nowait
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= input; i++)
                x = m * ( double ) ( 2 * i - 1 );
                sum = sum + 1.5 / ( 1.0 + x * x );
        }
    }
}
```

And I am not sure this sections parallelization is how it should be parallelized.

Thanks

Comment: Remember that C isn't like python; indentation doesn't determine blocks. Your reduction variable isn't being used in the for loop...

Comment: Also declare your variables in their minimum scope... it saves so much effort in cases like this. (Do you *really* want x shared!?)